# count a value in database

Tags: java, jdbc

How I can count how many times a value appear in a table using jdbc? I have 200 possible values and 4 columns for records in the table.

Comment: Do you want a count of each value, or just one?

Answer (score 5):

May be by

```
Select count(*) from table where item = 'value';
```

If you want count for all 200 values then you can try:

```
select item,count(*) from table group by item;
```

---

Demo code:--

```
try {
         java.sql.Statement s = conn.createStatement();
         java.sql.ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("select item,count(*) from table group by item;");
        while (r.next()) {
            System.out.println(r.getString(1) + " "
                    + r.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: thanks  alot but could you explain to me how to write this statement in java program. i try to put in my program but i get nullpointer exception.tq

Comment: @user692495: if my answer solves your problem then you should accept it by clicking on green right mark; so others can know its a correct answer.